# PHP: get multiple object in json from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

get_post.php

```
<?php
require_once 'database_config/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $location = $_POST['location'];

    $db = new DbOperations();

    $post = $db->getPostByLocation($location);

    $response['id'] = $post['id'];
    $response['name'] = $post['name'];
    $response['gender'] = $post['gender'];
    $response['dob_year'] = $post['dob_year'];
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

ObOperations.php

```
public function getPostByLocation($location)
    {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("select * from table_post where location = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $location);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array();
    }
```

Hi, what I am trying to do is to get JSON objects for all data that has a certain location data. When I type New Jersey, then it should get objects for all data that has "New Jersey" location data. But, it only prints one data. How can I get all data in json format. ObOperations has getPostByLocation function and it works correctly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `$stmt->get_result()->fetch_array();` you just get the first row, you should use `while` loop for retrive all the row, e.g.

```
<?php
public function getPostByLocation($location)
{
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("select * from table_post where location = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $location);
    $stmt->execute();

    $data = array();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but after I added this, the json prints null for all elements

Comment: Then you `$post` should receive an array, let's `print_r` it out to see what it contains

Comment: print_r($post); does not print anything.

Comment: sorry typepo please change update the while return code, add `$data` then `$data[] = $row;` and `return $data;`

Comment: Oh, print_r($post) prints all the arrays with data correctly, but it doesn't still get objects in json.

Comment: Oh I am supposed to echo json_encode($post)! it seems like it is printing all values correctly but every values are printed twice with [0] => values
 [1] => values like this

Comment: You may return the $post directly? are you looking for some like this? [{'id':'xxx','name':'xxx','gender':'xxx','dob_year':'xxx'},{'id':'xxx','name':'xxx','gender':'xxx','dob_year':'xxx'},{'id':'xxx','name':'xxx','gender':'xxx','dob_year':'xxx'}]

Comment: after chaning fetch_array to fetch_assoc, everything works as expected! thank you so much for your help :) I will upvote

Comment: $result->fetch_array will also result the key, so try to use fetch_assoc